# Is it possible to use ChaCha20 and Poly1305 in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, openssl

I would like to enable **ChaCha20** and **Poly1305** for TLS in nodejs, but if I run `tls.getCiphers()` on nodejs v6.10.3 running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS , they are not there.

So is this possible without building a custom nodejs on my own? Can I maybe drop in these ciphers by using pure JavaScript?

Any information would be highly appreciated. I need this because I am communicating with an IoT-device that does not have support for HW-accelerated AES and using ChaCha20 would probably improve performance quite a bit.

Comment: The cipher suites are part of TLS 1.3. You will need OpenSSL 1.1.0 to get them. That probably means building OpenSSL and Node.js from sources. I also recommend using RPATH's for both as discussed at [Compilation and Installation | Using RPATHs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Using_RPATHs) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd rather not have to do this on my own, since I would then have a nodejs version on my own to maintain and update. Do you happen to now if OpenSSL 1.1.0 is scheduled to enter nodejs sometimes in the near future?

Comment: I don't know what Node.js plans are with respect to OpenSSL. Distro's will likely take years to adopt OpenSSL 1.1.0. You will probably need to maintain it yourself until distro's catch up. I use a build script for occasions like this ("this" means I need something critical updated, like SSH or Git). Also see [Noloader | Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts) GitHub. The SSH one is similar to what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for this. Googled around and if i interpret this posting correctly, it looks like it is scheduled for Node.js 9:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/11828

Comment: @jww this is only partially correct. You do need OpenSSL 1.1.0 to get ChaCha20/Poly1305 based ciphersuites. However they are available in TLSv1.2. OpenSSL 1.1.0 does not support TLSv1.3.

Comment: @MattCaswell - So I am clear (forgive my ignorance): ChaCha/Poly1305 is part of TLS 1.2 and 1.3. However, OpenSSL is not back-porting  ChaCha/Poly1305 to OpenSSL 1.0.2. In addition, to get  ChaCha/Poly1305, you need to use OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev or above. Is that correct?

Comment: @jww Yes, ChaCha/Poly1305 is part of TLS 1.2 and 1.3. Yes, OpenSSL is not back-porting ChaCha/Poly1306 to 1.0.2. You can get ChaCha/Poly1305 in OpenSSL 1.1.0 (using TLS1.2). To get ChaCha/Poly1305 in TLS1.3 you need 1.1.1-dev.

Comment: @MattCaswell - Thanks. I think this was the piece I was missing: *"You can get ChaCha/Poly1305 in OpenSSL 1.1.0 (using TLS1.2)"*. I think I saw Andy's check-in, but I did not understand it. Probably because I did not realize it was for TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this myself on 10/19/2017.

There is no available support in Node 6, 7, 8 or even in the upcoming 9.

The last message seen from TSC (regarding this matter) is a protocol from this meeting: https://github.com/nodejs/TSC/pull/387/files

So it looks like there might be support for ChaCha20 and Poly1305 in node.js 10, if they can sort out the FIPS issues for OpenSSL 1.1.