# Using chacha20-poly1305 with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, encryption

Older versions of node [did not support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44604669/2371861) chacha20-poly1305, but [as of version 10.0.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V10.md#10.0.0), node supported openssl 1.1.0, which includes chacha.

- `require('tls').getCiphers()` includes chacha.
- `$ openssl ciphers` includes chacha.

But passing `https.createServer()` and `http2.createServer()` a `ciphers` list with only chacha causes a *no shared cipher* error when connecting with a browser that supports chacha. An example list of ciphers:

```
https.createServer({
    // ...
    'ciphers': [
        'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256',
        'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256',
        'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256',
        'TLS_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256',
        'TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256',
        'TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256',
        'TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256'
    ].join(':')
}, someFunction).listen(443);
```

Is it a bug with node or some other configuration option I've overlooked?

Comment: Use the ssllabs.com SSL tester to connect to your server and examine the output.

Comment: @JamesKPolk All I get using the `ciphers` list in the question is "Assessment failed: Failed to communicate with the secure server". It succeeds in generating a report if I add non-chacha ciphers to the end of the list (with `honorCipherOrder`), but the cipher suite list and handshake simulations make no mention of chacha.

Comment: The ssllabs tester does support the chacha ciphersuites, so to me it seems that, despite your configuration, your server does not support them. I have no idea why.

Comment: Note that adding support for a ciphersuite consists of more than just having a mode available. So it is not that strange that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mscdex [explained](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21553) on GitHub, the strings I were trying to use were in the wrong format. `tls.getCiphers()` will return the valid strings, if you convert the strings from it to upper case.

For example, the following:

```
tls.getCiphers().filter((str) => str.includes('chacha')).map((str) => str.toUpperCase())
```

Returns this for me:

```
[ 'DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
  'DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
  'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
  'ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
  'ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
  'PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
  'RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305' ]
```